# How to remediate damage to a young tree branch from continued squirrel use

Tags: trees, pest-damage, squirrel

**Context**

There is a what I believe to be a small dogwood in my backyard very close to the house. Fox squirrels frequently jump from the tree onto my roof. They all use the same spot on the same branch. The branch is, as a result, frequently getting scratched and damaged on that spot. The branch is thinner than a paper towel cardboard tube. Image below.

**Questions**

Should I treat the branch?

Is there a way to protect the branch from future damage?[image: squirrel damaged branch]

**Notes**

I do not want to remove the squirrels or otherwise harm them . Also given my area removal isn't an option given their very large local population.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tree Guards or tree trunk protectors are commonly available at nurseries or farm supply stores or Amazon too.  They are a flexible plastic tube with holes to allow drainage and venting and they have a "memory" so they stay rolled up.

If you bought one on put it around the branch that should do the job nicely as the diameter of the branch in the picture is a close match for the newly planted saplings it is normally used for.

Comment: Note that you would have to remove the guard as the branch grew or risk girdling that branch. Have you considered removing that branch, or would doing that just move the squirrels to a new launching pad?

Comment: @Jurp I see these guards on many new plantings.  As the trunk grows the guard expands in diameter. Very helpful with beaver too

Comment: I think it depends on the manufacturer - I've seen far more guards either "popping" off of the trunks or digging into the trunks than expanding with them. I do not like them at all for trunk protection because they allow insects to hide from predators (and possibly chew the bark) and more importantly, allow fungus to grow and thrive beneath them. I prefer cylinders made of hardware cloth - open to the air, open to the sun, and excellent protection from all critters. In the OP's case, though, I think a tree guard is a good idea to help protect the branch from squirrels.